# Error loading less module in react

Tags: reactjs, webpack, css-loader, less-loader

When I try to import a `.less` from my React component I get the following error:

```
Module not found: '[object Object]' in /path/to/src
```

Here's a part of my webpack config that's taking care of css and less loading:

```
...
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
      fallback: 'style-loader',
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'css-loader',
          options: {
            modules: true,
            importLoaders: true,
            localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
          }
        },
        'postcss-loader'
      ]
    })
  },
  {
    test: /\.less$/,
    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
      fallback: 'style-loader',
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'css-loader',
          options: {
            modules: true,
            sourceMap: true,
            importLoaders: true,
            localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
          }
        },
        'less-loader'
      ]
    })
  },
...
```

In my component, I'm importing the `.less` style file, like so:

```
import styles from './App.less'
```

I've tried reading related github issues and been debugging this for a while. Would love some help!

Comment: Have you tried `loader: 'less-loader'` instead of just `less-loader`?

Comment: do you mean in the object that tests for `test: /\.less$/` ? At the end using { loader: 'less-loader' }. That doesn't work either

Comment: Yes, the exact same setup you have just with `loader` before you specify the actual loader.

Comment: Also, `less-loader` compiles `.less` files to `.css` which I think are the files you are supposed to import as opposed to importing `.less` files themselves.

Comment: That's an excellent point, but I'm aware of applications that load `.less` files directly into the component. In the same way, components can also load `.scss` files and webpack will take care of parsing it behind the scenes

Comment: Alright, no problem. Did you try what I suggested? Did it work?

Comment: Yup I did try it, unfortunately it still throws the same error. Also tried using `.css`; that fails too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158752/discussion-between-fshock-and-vjrngn).